# Is Health kit framework support in iPad Only app?

Tags: ios, ipad, healthkit

I have an iPad App and i want to access Health kit store data. is it possible in iPad application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, from the official [HealthKit Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/):

> HealthKit and the Health app are unavailable on iPad.

Comment: And still nothing changes with iOS 11